# How to create a list/dict and export the values to Excel from multiple PDF files

Tags: python, pdf, reader

I'm doing a Pdfreader that will get the information from Energy Bills PDF in a directory. The program is running and printing exactly as I want to 'store' the information.

The next steps is:

Export to excel the values from each bills, exactly as print in console:
[Console image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NnRgZ.png)

I've tried lists, dictionaries. Maybe in a wrong way, but none of trials was sucessful.

Any improvements and other ways to do the same, but smarter, is welcome.

Follow the code

```
import glob

from PyPDF2 import PdfFileReader
pdf_dir = "C:/Users/gabri/Desktop/py4e/Contas EDP AAP/Leitor PDF/Faturas"
pdf_files = glob.glob("%s/*.pdf" % pdf_dir)
path = pdf_files

for file in pdf_files:
    with open(file, 'rb') as f:
        pdf = PdfFileReader(f)
        page = pdf.getPage(1)
        text = page.extractText()
        text = text.split()

        for word in text:
            if word.endswith('Créditos'):
                word = word.replace("Créditos", "")
                word = word.replace("mês", "")
                word = word.replace("kWh", "")
                energia_injetada = word
                print('Energia injetada: ', energia_injetada)

            elif word.endswith('Saldo'):
                word = word.replace("mês", "")
                word = word.replace("Saldo", "")
                word = word.replace("Participação", "")
                word = word.replace("kWh", "")
                energia_injetada = word
                if 'Recebido' not in word:
                    print('Energia injetada: ', energia_injetada)

            elif word.endswith('Saldo'):
                word = word.replace("Recebido", "")
                word = word.replace("kWhSaldo", "")
                recebidos = word
                print(recebidos)

            elif word.endswith('Participação'):
                word = word.replace("mês", "")
                word = word.replace("Saldo", "")
                word = word.replace("Participação", "")
                word = word.replace("kWh", "")
                energia_injetada = word
                print('Saldo Atualizado: ', energia_injetada)

            elif word.startswith('Verde'):
                print('Bandeira verde')

            elif word.startswith('Vermelha:'):
                print('Bandeira vermelha')

            elif word.startswith('Amarela'):
                print('Bandeira Amarela: ')

            elif word.startswith('('):
                word = word.replace("(", "")
                data_inicial = word
                print('Data inicial: ', data_inicial)

            elif word.endswith(')Nº'):
                word = word.replace(")Nº", "")
                data_final1 = word
                print("Data Final: ", data_final1)

            elif word.endswith(")Agradecemos"):
                word = word.replace(")Agradecemos", "")
                data_final = word
                print('Data final: ', data_final)

            elif word.startswith('Saldo'):
                word = word.replace("Saldo", "")
                participacao_saldo = word
                print('Participação no Saldo: ', participacao_saldo)

                print('\n\n')

            else:
                continue

if __name__ == '__main__' :
    print('ok')
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use print:

```
with open('out.csv', 'w') as fileout:
    with open(file, 'rb') as f:
        #some code
        print("hi", "data", file=fileout,sep=";")
```